# Reading RMS Data of other Midlet

Tags: midlet, s60, java-me, rms

I want to Read RMS Data created by one midlet from second midlet

Target devise are S60 is it possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. Open a record store associated with the named MIDlet suite. The MIDlet suite is identified by MIDlet vendor and MIDlet name. Access is granted only if the authorization mode of the RecordStore allows access by the current MIDlet suite.

Access is limited by the authorization mode set when the record store was created:

- **AUTHMODE_PRIVATE** - Succeeds only if
  vendorName and suiteName identify the
  current MIDlet suite; this case
  behaves identically to
  openRecordStore(recordStoreName,
  createIfNecessary).
- **AUTHMODE_ANY** - Always succeeds. Note
  that this makes your recordStore
  accessible by any other MIDlet on the
  device. This could have privacy and
  security issues depending on the data
  being shared. Please use carefully.
  Untrusted MIDlet suites are allowed
  to share data but this is not
  recommended. The authenticity of the
  origin of untrusted MIDlet suites
  cannot be verified so shared data may
  be used unscrupulously.

See this links for your reference.

1. [Sharing Data Between MIDlet
   Suites](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/sharedrms/index.html)
2. [Advanced Programming](http://carnations.blog.binusian.org/2010/10/29/j2me-tutorial-part-iii-advanced-programming-and-api-programming/)